# Typesetting: Lining up footnote marker with cap or ascender line of the text (FN too high)

Tags: footnotes, typography, superscripts, layout

How can I line up the footnote marks with the cap or ascender line (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) of a text? Usually LaTex would use superscripts, which appear to be placed slightly higher than the text itself.

As you can see in the MWE, the top of the "1" is slightly higher than the top line of the "P". Same for the footenote, where the top of the 1 is higher than the top of the A. What I actually want is shown in the picture, where the 1 perfectly fits the red line (did  the img with image editing).

Since many typesetters tend to line it up I would like to work with these standards myself as well.

The realscripts package seems not to help at all.

Here is my MWE (using XeLatex). Thank you for any helpful advice!

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
This is some Text with a footnote and its marker is too high P\footnote{And this the footnote text.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the visible height of a character may not equal its reported height.  This has always been a problem.

This arbitrarily uses the height of the letter P, presumably in the current font size.  This is often less than `\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\newsavebox{\testbox}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\savebox{\testbox}{P}\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\testbox-\height}{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is some Text with a footnote and its marker is too high P\footnote{And this the footnote text.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @john, that solves the problem for footnotemarks in the running text. However, the footnotemarker at the beginning of the footnote apparatus at the end of the page are not affected buy this fix.

Comment: `\@makefntext` depends on the document class, but the article definition (which I added) uses `\@makefnmark`.