# Customization of footnotes distance with the word

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I want to add spaces between the number of footnotes with the word in the main text, not at the page's bottom. Let me show you what I'm looking for. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\footnote{a footnote}
\blindtext  

\end{document}
```

which gives a simple text. Here is what I want:
[image]

I want the number of the footnote to be printed a little upper than it is. How can I figure it out? Thanks.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669227/typesetting-lining-up-footnote-marker-with-cap-or-ascender-line-of-the-text-fn

Comment: It lowers the number. If you know how to change that, please give your idea as the answer to the question. thanks

Comment: \raisebox can either raise or lower by any amount.  Is 1ex high enough?

Comment: Yes, It's great. Please type the code to announce it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want superscript?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\raisebox{1ex}{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\footnote{a footnote}
\blindtext  

\end{document}
```